# How to allow user to edit Purchase Order type at any time?

Tags: abap, sap-erp, purchase-order

Client has requested if it would be possible to **edit** the **PO type**, i.e. using the transaction `ME22N`, in any scenario.

Is there a way in ABAP to make this change?

Answer (score 0):

No, order type cannot be edited after PO creation (ME21n).

ME22n is the order edit transaction which allows edit *some* order parameters, but not all. and order type is the fundamental PO parameter which defines bunch of business logic: release strategy, delivery schedule, billing, shipping and so on.

It is conceptually wrong to try to change the order type on order change, it's simpler to create a new order with a correct type.